# Is it possible to record 2 camera streams at Full HD resolution at the same time ? (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, camera, frame-rate

I have 2 `See3Cam_CU20` usb cameras on a `Lenovo Thinkpad T14` (Ubuntu 18.04 ,Core i5 Vpro 10th gen, 16 GB Ram, 512GB SSD) the camera has a maximum of 28 FPS at FHD.

I want to record 2 video streams at Full HD resolution (1920, 1080) to my disk.
I am using `Python 3.8.5` and `opencv-python 4.4.0`, `VideoCapture` for grabbing the frames and `VideoWriter` for saving the frames into the disk( for each camera there is a seperate thread for reading the frames from the camera and another thread for saving the frames into disk).

[image: Result]

The recording was made for a 1000 seconds period ,from the above results it seems that there is a bottleneck in my implementation, the frames recorded are lower than the frames captured dropping the `FPS` to `20-22 fps`.
is there any python solution to capture 2 video streams at `FHD` and saving to disk in real time ?
If so what could be the bottleneck?

Comment: If you want to record the streams, and you don't need any kind of real-time speed, you could create dedicated threads for capturing the image of each camera, with "big"buffers to avoid frame dropping. 

I recommend you to make introduce timestamps at every captured frame. The camera drivers and the OS do weird things sometimes.

Comment: The real time speed is a necessity in my use case, but the frame dropping occurs in the recording not in the capturing of the frames, I will introduce the timestamps and see what kind of insights I could get from that.